# How to Grab URL/Id of Newly Created Record

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference, url, id

My visual force page requests 5 inputs. WeatherController then posts those inputs to Chatter and also creates a record from the information. What I'm not understanding is how to "grab" the URL of the newly created record so that I can publish it as a link in Chatter along with the other 5 inputs. **How do I automatically grab the url of a newly created record in Apex?**

[image: VisualForce]
[image: APEX]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two insert statement into your code

```
 insert WT;
 insert fItem;
```

You can get both record id by

```
     WT.id and fItem.id
```

and you can build url for both item in following way before return null statement

```
    String WTUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+WT.Id;
    String fItem = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+fItem.Id;
```

Comment: It Worked! You da best! Thank you! Your answer also helped me realize that I needed to rearrange some of the statements.

Comment: please upvote and mark this as answer :)

Comment: Done and done..